# Running a For loop only results in the final data frame created

Tags: python, pandas

```
countries = ['EMU','Ger','Fra','Ita','Spa','UK','Swe','Nor','Swi','US','Jpn','Cad','Nzd','Aus','Pol','Skr']

for country in countries:
    df_name = 'df' + country
    df_name = df[[country + '_OECD_LI',country + '_Man_Conf',country + '_C_Conf',country + '_Serv_Conf',country + '_Av']].copy()
    
df_EMU}
```

I basically need a dataframe for each country which contains the related column from my main dataframe.

This code returns a df called "Df_name", which has the correct data from the final observation (Skr).

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you overwrite the `df_name` variable with each iteration

Comment: Yeah thanks, do you know how I would store each df on each iteration?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Any tutorial on looping and data sequences (e.g. list) will teach you how to accumulate results.  We expect you to use those resources before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

1. The dataframe `df_name` has the data of only the last iteration because you're always assigning to the variable `df_name`.
2. It looks like you're trying to create dataframe variables with the name of the country, so `df_EMU`, `df_Ger`, `df_Fra`, etc. You can't create variables by doing `df_name = 'df' + country`. You *could* use `locals()` to create variables dynamically and assign values to them, but that's usually not necessary, or good practice. Later on in your code, how would know which country varialbes you have available to use in code you're writing?
3. An easier solution is to create a dictionary of dataframes. Each key would be the country name/code and the value would be the associated dataframe.

   ```py
   countries = ['EMU','Ger','Fra','Ita','Spa','UK','Swe','Nor','Swi','US','Jpn','Cad','Nzd','Aus','Pol','Skr']
   dfs = {}  # empty dictionary
   for country in countries:
       dfs[country] = df[[country + '_OECD_LI',
                          country + '_Man_Conf',
                          country + '_C_Conf',
                          country + '_Serv_Conf',
                          country + '_Av']].copy()

   # You can then refer to the country dataframes with:
   dfs['EMU']
   dfs['Ger']
   dfs['Fra'] # etc.
   ```

   That way, all the countries available are keys in the dictionary `dfs`.

Btw, did you get a dataframe with the data of all countries as separate columns? Seems like an odd data source. Normally, it would be the Country as a column of names/codes and then different column for each feature ('OECD_LI', 'Man_Conf', etc.)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A little unclear what you want to do eventually with each df, but you could store each df in a new list:

```
countries = ['EMU','Ger','Fra','Ita','Spa','UK','Swe','Nor','Swi','US','Jpn','Cad','Nzd','Aus','Pol','Skr']

list_of_dfs = []
for country in countries:
    df_name = 'df' + country
    list_of_dfs.append(df[[country + '_OECD_LI',country + '_Man_Conf',country + '_C_Conf',country + '_Serv_Conf',country + '_Av']].copy())
```